# Error message in google recaptcha

Tags: c#, asp.net, recaptcha

I am using Google recaptcha for one of our projects. Is there any method to show the error messages after validating the reCaptcha.

I know that we can access the error message after validating it. I want to know that is there any inbuilt method to show error message

Comment: I think you yourself will have to use the error provided by them (like displaying to label etc). See if these tips help. http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/tips.html

Comment: @Subhash: yes i already tried like that ie binding error messages to label. thanks :-)

Comment: Looks like you have asked same question earlier, not sure what's the purpose of having duplicated question. If some moderator is around, I recommend closing this as exact duplicate.

Comment: Can't you just check the recaptcha control's IsValid? Also is there no error message property for the control? If there is, you can use  the plain ol' ASP.NET validation summary to display the messages on top and the ErrorMessage property to display it next to the control itself.